# Scraping plain html without attributes

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the date of this html without attribute

```
html= '''
<span class="title">Title</span>
<br/>
<b>Date: </b>
2016-04-02 
<b> at </b>           
09:15 
<b>hours.</b>
<br/>
<span class="menu">Menu</span>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all('b', recursive=False)
>>> [<b>Date: </b>, <b> at </b>, <b>h</b>]
```

Unfortunately, the date haven't html attributes and I am not sure if it can be obtained.

Comment: can you link me that website?

Comment: It is not a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `<b>` tag that contains "Date" and then find next text sibling.

For example:

```
html= '''
<span class="title">Title</span>
<br/>
<b>Date: </b>
2016-04-02
<b> at </b>
09:15
<b>hours.</b>
<br/>
<span class="menu">Menu</span>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

d = soup.select_one('b:contains("Date")').find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
2016-04-02
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, this solution help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dates =  soup.find('span',class_='title').get_text()
```

That is if span with class title is the only one on that page. You haven't provided an URL so hard to tell. The text is within the span tag NOT the b tag.